# Insert leading zero in month number string

Tags: r

I have a string input on month number, e.g. for October it is `"10"`,  for November it is `"11"`.

My first goal is to derive the next month number in string, e.g. if the string is `"10"` my output should be `"11"`. This works,

```
mon_num <- "09"
as.character(match(month.abb[as.numeric(mon_num) + 1], month.abb))
```

My second requirement is the string should have two characters. That means, if the input string is `"02"`, the output should be `"03"`. However, the above lines produce `"3"`. Is there any way to derive `"03"` instead of `"3"`.

My second problem is, if the input is `"12"`, the output is `NA`. How to make it `"01"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to handle this -

```
get_next_month <- function(mon_num) {
  stopifnot("month number should be between 1 and 12" = 
            mon_num >= 1 && mon_num <= 12)
  if(mon_num == 12) return("01")
  nm <- match(month.abb[as.numeric(mon_num) + 1], month.abb)  
  sprintf("%02i", nm)
}

get_next_month(2)
#[1] "03"
get_next_month(10)
#[1] "11"
get_next_month(12)
#[1] "01"
get_next_month(15)
```

> Error in get_next_month(15) : month number should be between 1 and 12

Answer (score 2):

Although not as complete a function as the other answer, this would work in one line:

```r
month_num <- "12"

sprintf("%02i", as.integer(month_num) %% 12 + 1)
# [1] "01"
```

### Edit - function for working with vectors/data.frames

If a function for adding a new column is useful, this will a) replace all months with next month, b) filter out all with invalid month numbers (>12; with warning) and c) safely return a vector/new column.

```r
add_chr_month <- function(months_in) {
  
  months_in <- as.integer(months_in)
  
  months_out <- sprintf("%02i", months_in %% 12 + 1)
  
  if(any(months_in > 12| months_in < 1)) {
    warning("Month values >12 or <1 detected, replacing with `NA`")
  }
  
  replace(months_out, months_in > 12 | months_in < 1, NA_character_)
  
}

df <- data.frame(months_in = sample(sprintf("%02i", 0:13)))

df$months_out <- add_chr_month(df$months_in)
#> Warning in add_chr_month(df$months_in): Month values >12 or <1 detected,
#> replacing with `NA`

df
#>    months_in months_out
#> 1         10         11
#> 2         00       <NA>
#> 3         11         12
#> 4         03         04
#> 5         02         03
#> 6         12         01
#> 7         04         05
#> 8         01         02
#> 9         09         10
#> 10        13       <NA>
#> 11        08         09
#> 12        05         06
#> 13        06         07
#> 14        07         08
```